# Does Order Number have to be an autonumber?

Tags: order

Can the Order Number on an Order be something other than an autonumber?

I want to set it to the order number from Shopify which is an alphanumeric value. Is this a a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

The Order Number field on Order is a standard field, allowing you to change the autonumber format only. You can't change the field type or anything else.

You can however use an External ID field to store the Shopify number into. This makes sense for integration purposes as well.